# Specify ImageUri in AWS::Lambda::Function throws CF error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

For some reason I'm unable to figure out why this is going wrong.

I've created a public ECR repository and I try to refer the image as `ImageUri` under the `Code` block in my AWS::Lambda::Function.

```
  SlackNotifierFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Join ["-", [!Ref Name, "slack", "notifier"]]
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      Code:
        ImageUri: public.ecr.aws/g9c9m7n7/aws-cost-anomaly-slack-notifier:latest
      Timeout: 1
      MemorySize: 128
      PackageType: Image
      Architectures: ["arm64"]
      Environment:
        Variables:
          LOG_LEVEL: INFO
          SLACK_TOKEN: !Ref SlackToken
          SLACK_CHANNEL: !Ref SlackChannel
```

CloudFormation throws the following error whilst creating the Lambda function.

> Resource handler returned message: "Source image
> public.ecr.aws/g9c9m7n7/aws-cost-anomaly-slack-notifier:latest
> is not valid. Provide a valid source image. (Service: Lambda, Status
> Code: 400, Request ID: 9150921d-4b35-44ae-a4eb-c137f2a779e9, Extended
> Request ID: null)" (RequestToken:
> 616bb226-a46b-faf1-c959-aad09880b137, HandlerErrorCode:
> InvalidRequest)

Here's the ECR public gallery link: https://gallery.ecr.aws/g9c9m7n7/aws-cost-anomaly-slack-notifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like providing an image uri referring to a public ECR gallery hosted image is not possible as of today.

Comment: Where did you find this information and how are you meant to now provide a public lambda function for that uses a container that will be used via CloudFormation across multiple unrelated AWS accounts?

Comment: I ask as I am trying to do the same thing and ran into the same error that you've posted above.